# ASP.Net List View EmptyItemTemplate not displaying

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms

I'm binding a ListView to a collection of objects which is working fine. Unfortunately when the collection is empty then I'm not getting the text in the EmptyItemTemplate element displayed as I would expect.

Markup code is

```
        <asp:ListView ID="lvBuildingContactsGrid" runat="server" 
            onitemcommand="lvBuildingContactsGrid_ItemCommand" >
            <LayoutTemplate>
                   <!-- some more html markup -->
             <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                   <!-- some more html markup -->
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                   <!-- some item makup -->           
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EmptyItemTemplate>
                   <p> empty text that isn't displaying </p>                
            </EmptyItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

The code behind to bind is

```
        ContactRoleCollection contactRoles = new ContactRoleCollection();
        contactRoles.ContactRoleSearchByBuildingID(int params);

        lvListView.DataSource = contactRoles;
        lvListView.DataBind();
```

When the collection returns a count of zero then the EmptyItemTemplate text doesn't display. I have viewed the page source and it isn't rendered at all (rather than being hidden). I have replaced the DataSource object just with null i.e.

```
lvListView.DataSource = null
```

Just to test it and it still doesn't work. No text rendered again.

I have had this problem on other pages I have worked on (and given up and done kludge work arounds) so it's obviously just something that I am missing - doing incorrectly.

Any input appreciated

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing [EmptyItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.emptyitemtemplate.aspx), which is rendered when there are no more data items to display in the last group of the current page, with [EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.emptydatatemplate.aspx), which is rendered when the data source does not contain any records.

From your question, it seems you need the latter. You should write:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <p>Empty text that will be displayed.</p>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Maybe this won't be rendering if you assign null as datasource. (Don't forget the .DataBind() ) Just use the 4 lines of code from above.